# ML : Match nonexhaustive error

Tags: sml

Hi I'm new to ML and I don't get how to fix this problem.

This is the code

```
datatype ttree = Empty | Node of int * ttree * ttree * ttree;

(* initialize the fist node *)

fun Addthird(K:int, Empty) = Node(K, Empty, Empty, Empty);

fun Addsecond(Y:int, K:int, Empty) = Node(Y, Empty, Addthird(K, Empty), Empty);

fun AddNode(T:int, Y:int, K:int, Empty) = Node(T, Empty, Addsecond(Y, K, Empty), Empty);
```

and this is the error

[ERROR-ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBIdG.png)

Thanks, Rico

Answer (score 3):

Just ask yourself what would happen if you called, say,

```
Addthird(0, Node(1, Empty, Empty, Empty))
```

Similarly for the other functions. A pattern match needs to cover all the cases, your definitions are only covering `Empty` as the last argument.